# SO can't create its own lobby and cannot be joined

Tags: splatoon-3

In splatoon 3, for some reason when I play with my SO I always have to create the group. If they created it, I can't see them as online, and when they are playing I can't just jump in next game.

Is there an option somewhere that might prevent 'seeing online' or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was from a year ago so it might already be resolved, but I'm still gonna spitball some ideas.

I can only say with this context to just make sure they're not blocked in your friend's list. If that doesn't work, [try these.](https://thedroidguy.com/nintendo-switch-cant-join-friend-1136855)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.